# regular expression Language of all those words that don’t contain the substring aaaa

Tags: regex

can anyone help me with the following regular expression 
Language of all those words that don’t contain the substring aaaa.
i just want to get the idea. i came up with the following R.E

```
" (ab)*(aaaaa)*"
```

any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: The use of the term "language" indicates that you might be approaching this from a more computer sciencey perspective, rather than a programming perspective. Are we allowed to use constructs like negative lookaheads, which aren't in CS definitions of regular expressions? In a practical program, we would just search for a match for `aaaa` and negate the result.

Comment: i am studying these in modelling and simulation subject

Comment: @pashaahmed: how is this a part of a *Modeling and Simulation course*, this should be part of *Fundamentals*, or *Automata and Computability*, but this has almost nothing to do with modeling nor simulating...

Comment: well i dont know :) i am students of bs in bioinformatics. it's our 7th sem course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
^((?!aaaa).)*$
```

This will match any combinations of length 0 or more of characters that not followed by `aaaa`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`aaaa` matches the characters aaaa literally (case sensitive)

`.` matches any character (except newline)

`*` Between zero and unlimited times

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AnXctDx0cXuWrz-7)

Also as an alternative and more efficient way in general as @CommuSoft says you can use the following pattern :

```
^(a{1,3}[^a]|[^a])*a{0,3}$
```

Comment: thanks. i want to learn more about these regular expressions. can you share an easy source   @kasra

Comment: @pashaahmed welcome but as far as i know this is the best and more elegant way for this problem! for more detail you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: If the regex engine doesn't use dynamic programming - which unfortunately many don't seem to do - it can result in a computationally intensive task... Another way to do this is `^(a{1,3}[^a]|[^a])*$` I think...

Comment: @CommuSoft As far as i know except bash mot of the popular lang support `look-around` and also dynamic programming

Comment: @Kasra: I don't say they don't support it, and `grep` does this as well btw (Java for instance doesn't). But it is in many cases not implemented with an efficient algorithm. Which is too bad...

Comment: @CommuSoft yep, in that case, i'm agree! i'll update the answer thanks for attention!

Comment: @Kasra: indeed, there is a small part missing `^(a{1,3}[^a]|[^a])*a{0,3}$`... Furthermore, dont forget the `^` and `$` markers in your answer, otherwise the regex will [simply match a small substring](https://regex101.com/r/oT0sX0/1).